# Wireless not available Ubuntu Server 16.04.01

Tags: 16.04, wireless, server, atheros

First post, so pardon my inexperience.

My network controller isn't showing up. I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 on an Asus TP200S notebook.

ifconfig yields:

```
lo    Link encap:Local loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1 etc...
```

I believe everyone's lo looks pretty much the same. However, there is no eth or wlan to speak of.

relevant lspci line:

```
2:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
```

rfkill is currently not installed, so no useful output there.

Comment: Please edit to add results for `dmesg | grep ath10k`

Answer (score 1):

So, I gave iwconfig a shot and learned that wireless-tools is not installed in Ubuntu server by default, in the expectation that you will have an ethernet connection.

Because my laptop does not, the solution was to install `wireless-tools` manually. In order to satisfy all the dependencies I also needed to install `libiw30`

I also chose to install `network-manager` for ease of configuration. This included following a lengthy dependency tree and installing everything via usb, so I don't recommend it.

I was able to use `nmcli` to connect to my network using [this tutorial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145366/how-to-connect-to-an-802-1x-wireless-network-via-nmcli).